# Indexing a URL in Google which has no any referral link in website

Tags: indexing, hyperlink, google-index

I have created a link such as http://example.com/s/an-arduino-product (in PHP), but there is no any referral link that refers to the above link in my website. If someone type this link on the browser, it will be redirected dynamically to a valid page (By reading information from database). My question is: What can I do extra work to make Google automatically recognize these links and index them? I will not do it manually via "Google Search Console".

Comment: submit this link in sitemap.xml and resubmit sitemap. Google index pages when you sitemap.xml those links only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a good idea. I will do it.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its works

Answer (score 1):

Submit this link in sitemap.xml and resubmit sitemap. Google will reindex pages when you submit sitemap.xml those links only.